# number distribution with AWK

Tags: awk

the script is given a list of 100 values ​​from 0 to 100, which distributes them by tens, displays the number of digits

```
10 number example:
4 2 22 1 2 2 3 33 84 84
cat numbets.txt|awk -f script.awk
0-9 : 5
10-19 : 0
20-29 : 1
30-39 : 1
40-49 : 0
50-59 : 0
60-69 : 0
70-79 : 0
80-89 : 2
90-99 : 0
100 : 0
```

How can I implement it with awk? Unfortunately, I've run out of ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, I've run out of ideas

You might to get desired result using integer division and using array of counters, consider following example, let `file.txt` content be

```
4 2 22 1 2 2 3 33 84 84
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]]"}{arr[int($1/10)]+=1}END{for(i=0;i<=10;i+=1){printf "%d0-%d9 : %d\n",i,i,arr[i]+0}}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
00-09 : 6
10-19 : 0
20-29 : 1
30-39 : 1
40-49 : 0
50-59 : 0
60-69 : 0
70-79 : 0
80-89 : 2
90-99 : 0
100-109 : 0
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that row separator is one or more whitespaces, this way each number is treated as single row. For each row I compute result of integer division by zero `int($1/10)` and then increase value under that key in array `arr`. After all lines are processed I use for loop to iterate over 0 to 10 (inclusive) and use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html) to output formatted text, which contain current value (twice) and corresponding value from array `arr`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: thanks, it worked!

Can you tell me if this is an option?

awk '{ 
 if      ($1 =< 10) first++
 else if ($1 > 10 && $1 <= 20)
 second++
 else if ($1 > 20 && $1 <= 30)      
 third++
 else if ($1 > 30 && $1 <= 40)
 fourth++
 else if ($1 > 40 && $1 <= 50)
 fifth++
 } END {
 print first,second,third,forth,fifth
 }' input.txt